# Разделение числа результата на разряды

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет! Есть простенький калькулятор, в нем содержится, как я понял, функция отделения остатка запятой на 1 разряд. Но нужно что бы, к примеру, число вида: #calcPrice=1472064, было представлено в виде: #calcPrice=1 472 064.
Вот как сейчас выводится результат: [image: скриншот]

```
var wasUsed = false;

function doCalc(){
    
    var meterPlus = 0;
    var totalMaterial = 0;
    var totalWorks = 0;
    var userInputSquare = $('#square').val();
    
    if($.isNumeric(userInputSquare) && userInputSquare <= 500){meterPlus = 3055;}else{meterPlus = 2706;}
    if($.isNumeric(userInputSquare) && userInputSquare <= 0){meterPlus = 0;}
    if(userInputSquare === ""){meterPlus = 0;}
    if($.isNumeric(userInputSquare) && userInputSquare <= 500){totalMaterial = (userInputSquare*meterPlus)*52/100;}else{totalMaterial = (userInputSquare*meterPlus)*57/100;}
    if($.isNumeric(userInputSquare) && userInputSquare <= 500){totalWorks = (userInputSquare*meterPlus)*48/100;}else{totalWorks = (userInputSquare*meterPlus)*43/100;}
    var totalPrice = userInputSquare*meterPlus;
    
    $('#meter').html(meterPlus);
    $('#material').html(totalMaterial);
    $('#works').html(totalWorks);
    $('#calcPrice').html(totalPrice);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('input', '#square, #material, #works, #calcPrice', function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));
        if($(this).val() > 9999) { $(this).val(1); }
        doCalc();
    });
    
    wasUsed = true; // init calc while not sending Yandex Goal
    doCalc();       
    wasUsed = false;
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#calcPrice').html(new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU').format(totalPrice));
```

Более подробно про форматирование текста: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting)